# [docusignapi]How to require password before recipient can see documents

Tags: docusignapi

[docusignapi]If I am sending a document for signature, can I require the user to know a password (which I would send separately?) before they can see the documents?

Comment: You should explore the Access Code feature. It can be set programmatically via the API. Initial details here [link](https://www.docusign.com/support/how-to-guides/access-code-authentication-0)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different recipient authentication methods that are available through the api.  As Luis mentions Access Code is one way.  You can set up an Access Code and send the actual separately through SMS, or you can just go ahead and use the SMS authentication through the api.  In addition to SMS there are things like Phone Authentication, Social ID Auth, and others.

Here are examples of the some of the signer authentication methods and how they would fit into your request body JSON:

```
"Signers": [{   
    "name": "Jone Doe",
    "email": "email@address.com",
    "recipientId": "309482348",

    ...

    "accessCode": "sample string 10",
    "requireIdLookup": "sample string 12",
    "idCheckConfigurationName": "sample string 13",
    "socialAuthentications": [
      {
        "authentication": "sample string 1"
      }
    ],
    "phoneAuthentication": {
      "recipMayProvideNumber": "sample string 1",
      "validateRecipProvidedNumber": "sample string 2",
      "recordVoicePrint": "sample string 3",
      "senderProvidedNumbers": [
        "sample string 1"
      ]
    },
    "samlAuthentication": {
      "samlAssertionAttributes": [
        {
          "name": "sample string 1",
          "value": "sample string 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "smsAuthentication": {
      "senderProvidedNumbers": [
        "sample string 1"
      ]
    },
```